# Check if NSString end with string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I would like to check if my NSString end with @2x.png (case insensitive). How can I do that?

I have this code now, but it seems to ignore the @2x part.

```
    NSString *fileName = [_sourcePath lastPathComponent];
    [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@2x" withString:@""];
    [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@2X" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Filename: %@", fileName);
```

> 2012-01-01 21:00:55.600 NewApp[23930:707] Filename: myfile@2x.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-assign your variable because NSString is immutable (state cannot be modifieid). Try:

```
NSString *fileName = [_sourcePath lastPathComponent];
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"2x" withString:@""];
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"2X" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Filename: %@", fileName);
```

Alternatively, if you want to do the replacements inline use a `NSMutableString` and `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range` which will do the replacement inline.

Comment: I should have known that. Its in the doc... just missed it. Changed it now together with @mvds suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
NSRange range = [fileName rangeOfString:@"@2x.png" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if ( range.location != NSNotFound &&
     range.location + range.length == [fileName length] )
{
    NSLog(@"%@ ends with @2x.png",fileName);
}
```

ps. Note that you should assure that `fileName` is not `nil` before calling `rangeOfString`, since you're calling a method which does not return `id`. Calling a method on `nil` returns `nil`, which is not compatible with the `NSRange` type, and will lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but it did not have the most up-to-date way of checking **if NSString end with string** (as per the title):

```
[fileName hasSuffix:@"@2x"];
```

Or case insensitive:

```
[[fileName lowercased] hasSuffix:@"@2x"];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a NSString so you can't change the content of the string. the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString return the modified string but IS NOT CHANGING the fileName string.

You need something like this:

```
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@2x" withString:@""];
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@2X" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Filename: %@", fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, you need to re-assign the result to your variable (or alternatively, create a mutable string with `-mutableCopy` and use the replacement methods in `NSMutableString`).

To do a case insensitive replacement, there is a second implementation of the same method with a few more arguments:

```
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@2x" withString:2"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, fileName.length)];
```